# Mapping JSON names to Java class fields/methods (Jackson Parser)

Tags: java, json, playframework, jackson

### Summary

How can I map a JSON name to a Java class' field name that might be (slightly) different when using the Jackson parser?

### Details

I have incoming JSON documents I would like to convert to a Java object using the [Jackson parser](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes). This works well for where the JSON names match the eventual Java object field names (I am doing this within the Play Framework).

However some JSON names in the incoming JSON document do not lend themselves to nice Java field names. Changing all the existing JSON documents to use proper Java naming conventions is currently not feasible.

For example

```
{
  "goodName": "value",
  "not-so-handy": "value"
}
```

I can't create a Java class with a field name of "not-so-handy" since that is not a legal name in Java.

How can I translate an incoming JSON name to a designated Java class' field name using the Jackson parser?

Comment: Annotations for renaming properties - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/#annotations-for-renaming-properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `@JsonProperty` :

```
@JsonProperty("goodName")
public String goodName;

@JsonProperty("not-so-handy")
public String notSoHandy;
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Is there a way to get the mapping defined by jackson annotation programmatically? ('not-so-handy' -> 'notSoHandy'). I need to translate a "sortField" argument from a REST service which references a _JSON_ field name. In the example you listed, the caller would call `list?sortField=not-so-handy` and I need to translate it to the Java bean field name "notSoHandy"

Comment: you can get the fieldname from URL, put it in the bean field of your choice.

Comment: I needed the mapping info ("not-so-handy" -> "notSoHandy"), not to parse or inject any value into a bean. I ended up reading class methods and annotation information, that was easier than I thought, but would have been great that Jackson exposes the mapping as it already knows it